# Is the SemiCovariance matrix positive definite?

Tags: statistics, covariance

I am trying to proof whether the SemiCovariance matrix defined in equation (5) from the following paper
http://web.iese.edu/jestrada/PDF/Research/Refereed/MSO.pdf
is positive definite or not.

As a starting point, I was thinking about using the whole covariance matrix, which is positive definite and then split it into the SemiCovariance and the rest. But from there I am stuck.

I appreciate your help.

Best,
Jc

Comment: You might want to extract the relevant definition so that people don't have to open up the link. In general, the question should stand on its own.

Comment: covariance matrices are PSD since they can be written in the form $A^TA$, can something not be done similarly for the semi covariance matrix?

Comment: Numerically, I am able to perform a Cholesky Factorization, but I have difficulties to visualize how this matrix looks like.